# What are animations and mixed fonts in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, configuration

What do "Enable animations" and "Use mixed fonts and colors for labels" under General > Appearance do?

I hate to ask about configurations, but Eclipse is just a mass of settings that no person or tutorial has been able to help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Enable animations' enables animation of a small number of operations - such as a job progresss window being minimized to the progress view. It isn't very useful.

'Use mixed fonts and colors for labels' allows separate fonts and colors to be used in things like decorations added to the main text in views such as Package Explorer.

For example - a Package Explorer entry with the option enabled:

[image: With]

with the option disabled:

[image: Without]